# Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin isn't work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-routing

I am using Ionic2. When I get GET data from service it prints to me this

```
error:Object{  
   _body:error,
   status:0,
   ok:false,
   statusText:"",
   headers:Object,
   type:3,
   url:null
}
```

I installed `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` plugin in chrome and use command:

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir ,
```

these solutions worked for one time but Once I closed the browser and reopen it I got that error again, Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Are you using Web APis? Can you show some code?

Comment: @MissakBoyajian i'm using ionic2: this is the function i used to get data from service : getCategories() {
    let objData = {"Data":{
            "action": "CATEGORIES",
            "lang": "AR"
        },
        "Request": {
         
        }
    }

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    {headers:headers}).map((response: Response) => response.json())
  }

}

Comment: did you try your code on real device ?

Comment: no i want to get data in browser befor

Comment: ok, the error happened even you run the `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` extention ?

Comment: @AbdElrahmanTelb it run once

Comment: Try turn off then on the extension